# Why typescript reports an error "Type '{}' has no property" on JS object destructuring

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've enabled type checking on my JavaScript project in Visual Studio Code. I'm getting an error when trying to do a destructuring assignment:

```
const { foo } = this.state;
```

results in an error

> [ts] Type '{}' has no property 'foo' and no string index signature.

While

```
const foo = this.state.foo;
```

works fine and doesn't report any errors.

Why is that happening? Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: What is `this.state` typed as? Seems ok in this example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IState%20%7B%20foo%3A%20number%20%7D%0Alet%20state%3A%20IState%20%3D%20%7B%20foo%3A%200%20%7D%3B%0Aconst%20%7B%20foo%20%7D%20%3D%20state%3B

Comment: Also, are you doing this inside of a class?

Comment: I'm not using typescript, so there is no explicit types defined anywhere. Just trying to see if VSCode can be helpful with automatic type checking https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking

`this.state` is a state in a react class component.

Answer (score 0):

With TypeScript we extend the `React.Component<P,S>` class to create React components. You also define the type used for props and state by passing the expected types as `<P,S>`

```
interface IProps {
    superVillian: string;
}

interface IState {
    health: string;
}

export class MyBoringComponent extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {

    render() {
        const { health } = this.state;
        return <span>{`${this.props.superVillian} health is: ${this.state.health}`}</span>
    }
}
```